# Angular 17 - should I switch from non-async pipe to async in *ngIf? Variable in ngIf is not updated anymore

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-ng-if

After upgrading Angular, I noticed that my component is displayed even if it should't.

```
<component-name *ngIf="!logged"></component-name>
```

logged == false, and it doesn't render as it should when I run ng serve. With SSR this component is rendered.

It works when I change this line to

```
<component-name *ngIf="(loggedInUpdated$ | async) == false"></component-name>
```

but... should I really update my whole app? It worked before and "logged" was updated properly in the html file.

.ts

```js
logged = false;

ngOnInit {
   this.auth.loggedInUpdated$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe(logged => this.onLoggedInUpdated(logged));
}

onLoggedInUpdated(logged: boolean) {
        this.logged = logged;
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    }
```

EDIT
I got it to work by adding :

```
this.onLoggedInUpdated(this.auth.getLoggedIn()); // it's getting the current state
```

in the ngOnInit().

But at that time, *logged == false*. Only after  this.auth.loggedInUpdated$ the value changes to true so it changes from false to true anyway. Maybe someone can help me understand this?

Comment: Can you also share the relevant part of the code both on `.ts` and `.html` side?

Comment: I added the .ts file. Logged is updated after getting the data from the localstorage - but I am checking if this is a client site, not server. Then it updates the value.

Comment: I see that it changed correctly in onLoggedInUpdated (and I see it on console.log) but Angular didn't destroy the <component-name> component in the DOM